# Any set of diameter $2r$ can be contained in a ball of radius $r$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

So I think the following statement is correct, but I don't really know how to go about showing it: If $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ has diameter $2r$, can it be contained in a closed ball of radius $r$? If not, I'd be real interested to see a counter-example. Thanks!

Comment: Equilateral triangle with sidelength $2r$.

Comment: You ought to make that an answer.

Comment: This paper has some results for convex sets. http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/016_99_JIPAM/016_99.pdf In particular, for convex sets, the $\sqrt{3}R\leq d \leq 2R$, apparently, with $2R$ the cirumradius and $d$ the diameter. I think that holds for non-convex sets, too. (Those results are for the plane.)

Answer (score 3):

An equilateral triangle with side length $2r$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you! Can we give a minimal bound, i.e. given a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, what's the minimum $C$ such that $S$ is contained in a ball of radius $R / C$?

Comment: @AJY In $\mathbb{R}$, the bound is still $2r$: By replacing $S$ with its convex hull we can only consider convex sets - but these are intervals.

Comment: Sorry, meant $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: @AJY Sorry, I don't know off the top of my head what the minimum is. But any set of diameter $2r$ can certainly be contained in a ball of radius $2r$. I'd *guess* that the most extreme example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a tetrahedron, though.